# Readiness and Liveness probes for elasticsearch 6.3.0 on Kubernetes failing

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, azure-aks, efk

I am trying to setup EFK stack on Kubernetes . The Elasticsearch version being used is 6.3.2. Everything works fine until I place the probes configuration in the deployment YAML file. I am getting error as below. This is causing the pod to be declared unhealthy and eventually gets restarted which appears to be a false restart.

Warning Unhealthy 15s kubelet, aks-agentpool-23337112-0 Liveness probe failed: Get http://10.XXX.Y.ZZZ:9200/_cluster/health: dial tcp 10.XXX.Y.ZZZ:9200: connect: connection refused

I did try using telnet from a different container to the elasticsearch pod with IP and port and I was successful but only kubelet on the node is unable to resolve the IP of the pod causing the probes to fail.

Below is the snippet from the pod spec of the Kubernetes Statefulset YAML. Any assistance on the resolution would be really helpful. Spent quite a lot of time on this without any clue :(

PS: The stack is being setup on AKS cluster

```
      - name: es-data
        image: quay.io/pires/docker-elasticsearch-kubernetes:6.3.2
        env:
        - name: NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        - name: NODE_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: CLUSTER_NAME
          value: myesdb
        - name: NODE_MASTER
          value: "false"
        - name: NODE_INGEST
          value: "false"
        - name: HTTP_ENABLE
          value: "true"
        - name: NODE_DATA
          value: "true"
        - name: DISCOVERY_SERVICE
          value: "elasticsearch-discovery"
        - name: NETWORK_HOST
          value: "_eth0:ipv4_"          
        - name: ES_JAVA_OPTS
          value: -Xms512m -Xmx512m
        - name: PROCESSORS
          valueFrom:
            resourceFieldRef:
              resource: limits.cpu
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 0.25
          limits:
            cpu: 1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9200
          name: http
        - containerPort: 9300
          name: transport
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            port: http
            path: /_cluster/health
          initialDelaySeconds: 40
          periodSeconds: 10
       readinessProbe:
         httpGet:
           path: /_cluster/health
           port: http
         initialDelaySeconds: 30
         timeoutSeconds: 10
```

The pods/containers runs just fine without the probes in place . Expectation is that the probes should work fine when set on the deployment YAMLs and the POD should not get restarted.

Comment: any update on this ? feel free to update the status of question by accepting the answer if any of resolve your answer or do upvote if found it helpful

Answer (score 6):

The thing is that ElasticSearch itself has own health statuses (red, yellow, green) and you need to consider that in your configuration.

Here what I found in my own ES configuration, based on [the official ES helm chart](https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/blob/a49995539e4347e8729437cfbb54299023c81306/elasticsearch/templates/statefulset.yaml#L181-L215):

```
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          initialDelaySeconds: 40
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 3
          timeoutSeconds: 5

          exec:
            command:
              - sh
              - -c
              - |
                #!/usr/bin/env bash -e
                # If the node is starting up wait for the cluster to be green
                # Once it has started only check that the node itself is responding
                START_FILE=/tmp/.es_start_file

                http () {
                    local path="${1}"
                    if [ -n "${ELASTIC_USERNAME}" ] && [ -n "${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}" ]; then
                      BASIC_AUTH="-u ${ELASTIC_USERNAME}:${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}"
                    else
                      BASIC_AUTH=''
                    fi
                    curl -XGET -s -k --fail ${BASIC_AUTH} http://127.0.0.1:9200${path}
                }

                if [ -f "${START_FILE}" ]; then
                    echo 'Elasticsearch is already running, lets check the node is healthy'
                    http "/"
                else
                    echo 'Waiting for elasticsearch cluster to become green'
                    if http "/_cluster/health?wait_for_status=green&timeout=1s" ; then
                        touch ${START_FILE}
                        exit 0
                    else
                        echo 'Cluster is not yet green'
                        exit 1
                    fi
                fi
```

Comment: I have checked - root `/` is available before `/_cluster/health`. So may be reasonable, but need to check how it works in cluster istio environment.

Answer (score 5):

First Please check the logs using

```
kubectl logs <pod name> -n <namespacename>
```

You have to first run the init container and change the volume permissions.

you have to run the whole config as the `user : 1000` also before the container of elasticsearch start you have to change the volume permission using init container.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  labels:
    app : elasticsearch
    component: elasticsearch
    release: elasticsearch
  name: elasticsearch
spec:
  podManagementPolicy: Parallel
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app : elasticsearch
      component: elasticsearch
      release: elasticsearch
  serviceName: elasticsearch
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app : elasticsearch
        component: elasticsearch
        release: elasticsearch
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: cluster.name
          value: <SET THIS>
        - name: discovery.type
          value: single-node
        - name: ES_JAVA_OPTS
          value: -Xms512m -Xmx512m
        - name: bootstrap.memory_lock
          value: "false"
        image: elasticsearch:6.5.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: elasticsearch
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9200
          name: http
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 9300
          name: transport
          protocol: TCP
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 250m
            memory: 1Gi
          requests:
            cpu: 150m
            memory: 512Mi
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
          runAsUser: 1000
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
          name: elasticsearch-data
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      initContainers:
      - command:
        - sh
        - -c
        - chown -R 1000:1000 /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
        - sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
        - chmod 777 /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
        - chomod 777 /usr/share/elasticsearch/data/node
        - chmod g+rwx /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
        - chgrp 1000 /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
        image: busybox:1.29.2
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: set-dir-owner
        resources: {}
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
          name: elasticsearch-data
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
  updateStrategy:
    type: OnDelete
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      name: elasticsearch-data
    spec:
      accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 10Gi
```

Check out the my yaml config and you can use. It's for single node of elasticsearch

Answer (score 0):

Probe outlined in my answer works in 3 nodes discovery when `Istio` presented. If `livenessProbe` is bad, than k8s will restart container even not allowing to start properly. I use internal Elastic ports (for node to node communication) to test liveness. These ports speak TCP.

```
      livenessProbe:
        tcpSocket:
          port: 9300
        initialDelaySeconds: 60 # it takes time from jvm process to start start up to point when discovery process starts
        timeoutSeconds: 10

          - name: discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes
          value: "2"
          - name: discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts
          value: elastic
```

Comment: What is "next next probe"?